Deceptive website warning for safari browser (not for chrome) , nginx+react+nodejs
Safari and Brave and maybe some other browsers react with a warning towards our website (Deceptive website warning)
We have a nginx set up that proxy passes to localhost , where node returns build version of react.
This is nginx configurattion
server {
    listen 443 ssl  http2;
    server_name ad-yo-ad.com www.ad-yo-ad.com;

    # SSL certificate paths (replace with your actual certificate paths)
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ad-yo-ad.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ad-yo-ad.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Improved SSL settings
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    # HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    # Content Security Policy
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https:; script-src 'self' https:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none';" always;

    # Other security headers
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" always;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # Handle WebSocket connections
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;

}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain_name.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain_name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name www.domain_name.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

This is how build is served
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
})


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Tried adding secure headers , checking all websites that check certificates etc , sslLabs gives A+ , but no result
